# counter in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

counter in a  recursive function - I have a function trying to find the largest number in a list.of-course j is going to be set back to 0, where should the counter declaration be?

```
  import random



list = []

for i in range(0, 10):
    number = random.randint(0, 100)
    list.append(number)

print(list)


def bigger_number (list):
    j = 0.  #where to place this
    n = list[0]  #where to place this
    while j < 9:
        if n >= list[j]:
            list[j] = n
            j+=1
            bigger_number(list)




print("The biggest number in the list is : ",n)

bigger_number(list)
```

Comment: Why is this a recursive function? What is `n`?  If `n < list[j]`, what will the next iteration of the loop be?

Comment: Sorry I just put in the function , n is list[0] therefore the first variable of the list,(not all code was given)

Comment: Please produce a [mcve]

Comment: try to make a diagram for the algorithm here, it mke no sense how u r finding the larrgest no

Comment: updated, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want a bigger number from an array using recursive solution.

If yes, then Try below function:

```
# ListA = [123,45,89,58]
# lenA = len(ListA) 

def bigger_Number(ListA, lenA): 
    if (lenA == 1): 
        return ListA[0] 
    return max(ListA[lenA - 1], bigger_Number(ListA, lenA - 1))
```

Comment: @mad_ Yes, I executed my code and I tried to rename variables for better understanding and forgot one variable. This new edit will work.

Comment: @dadu300 for your understanding I renamed variables in my code.